# Accessing data in a php multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array and php seems to be returning an array instead of a value when I attempt to access the values directly.  What am I doing to cause this?

The array looks like (via print_r):

```
Array ( 
[12] => Array ( [2016] => 93083.00 [2015] => 85367.00 [2014] => 69726.00 ) 
[11] => Array ( [2016] => 66730.00 [2015] => 65548.00 [2014] => 77936.00 ) 
[10] => Array ( [2016] => 84602.00 [2015] => 112070.00 [2014] => 102104.00 )
 )
```

I'm trying to access values using `$arrayname[12][2016]` but it is returning `Array[2016]` instead of `93083`.

Is this a simple syntax mistake?  Or am I missing part of the concept here?  I've been trying to work this problem for hours so maybe I'm missing a simple explanation.

EDIT: the syntax above is actually correct, the issue was in the data entry: I was trying to access a key that didn't exist.  I tried to delete the post, but can't since it has been answered.

Comment: Please show how you're attempting to print it out, because that is correct.

Comment: `echo $chart3_array[1][2017];` doesn't output anything, while `print_r($chart3_array);` does.

Comment: Could this possibly be a type issue with the second key?  I've tried it both as 2017 and "2017" though.

Comment: I found it, it was an error in the data being entered.  Thanks for your help.  I will delete the question shortly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayname[12] = [2016=>93083.00,  2015=> 85367.00 ] 
    ...
    ...
    echo $arrayname[12][2015] ; // prints 85367
```

i think your array has one more level. try **$arrayname[12][2016][2016]** .